# XUnit plugin for VS2013 "not yet published", so where to find it?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, tdd, xunit.net

I'm trying to install XUnit to test out the GitReleaseNotes package. When googling, i found the below problematic web page? Is there another place to find this?

[Products and Extensions for Visual Studio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/463c5987-f82b-46c8-a97e-b1cde42b9099)

> Products and Extens This item is not yet published. If you are the owner of this project, please sign in with the appropriate account. ions for Visual Studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XUnit Runner is now a NuGet package and is no longer distributed as a vsix. Downloadable from here:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit.runner.visualstudio/0.99.9-build1021